# Is it correct: "Let's suppose someone is trying to disarm you."

Tags: grammaticality

I need help with the following sentence:

> Let's assume that somebody tries to disarm it.

For example, at a demonstration for demonstration purposes on a [quizlets](http://quizlets.live/) product.

My first thought was that I put it like it was going to happen. Accordingly, I thought this option would be correct.

> Let's suppose someone is trying to disarm you.

Would that be correct? Or would you formulate the sentence in a completely different way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both phrases are correct as stand alone phrases, why would you suppose they might not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The sentence is valid, and there are variants...

["Assume"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assume) is synonymous with "suppose to be true", which can be shortened to "suppose". So assume and suppose are synonymous.

The same goes for ["somebody" and "someone"](https://writingexplained.org/someone-vs-somebody-difference), they are next to entirely interchangeable, although "someone" seems to be considered slightly more formal.

The sentence has two parts. First the speaker is enjoining the listener to make a thought experiment.

This can take several forms:

- *Assume that...*
- *Assuming that...*
- *If we make the assumption that...*
- *Imagine that...*
- *Let us suppose that...*
- *If you picture that...*
- *Posit that...*

The second part of the sentence describes what the speaker wants the listener to imagine in this thought experiment, and that too can be expressed in many ways.

*Let us assume that **someone**/**somebody**...*

- *...is trying to disarm it*
- *...is attempting to disarm it*
- *...will try to disarm it*
- *...will make an attempt to disarm it*
- *...takes a shot at disarming it*
- *...is disarming it, or at least trying to*
- *...may try to disarm it*

So there you have nearly 100 different ways (7 x 2 x 7) of expressing the exact same thing, and then we have not even nearly exhausted all possible permutations and variants of it.

P.S: [*"Assumption — my dear Mitzi — is the mother of all..."*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109045/quotes/qt0404942)